# Contact Form 7 - Get final mail HTML output

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

Is there a hook that will allow me to see exactly what is being sent out to an email?

I've tried using `'wpcf7_mail_sent'` and all it contains is array of the data and fields.

For example it has `"first-name": "John", "last-name": "Smith", ...` etc. but not template.

What I want to get is the mail template merged with that data... aka the final email as HTML:

For example: `Hello, John Smith! <br> Thanks for contacting us.`

### Edit: Clarification

(Using the example that @Howard E provided)

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'dd_handle_form_submission', 10, 3 );
function dd_handle_form_submission( $contact_form,$abort,$submission ) {

    $template = $contact_form->prop('mail')['body'];
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

    //Outputs:
    //$template: <h2> First Name: [first-name] </h2>    <h2> Last Name: [last-name] </h2> ...
    //$posted_data: Array ( [first-name] => 'John', [last-name] => 'Smith' ... )
}
```

That's the template but with shortcodes... and the data but as an array.

My original question was how do I get the final output of the merged `$posted_data` + `$template` so an `$html` var would look like this:

`"<h2> First Name: John </h2>    <h2> Last Name: Smith </h2>"`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email body is in the class `WPCF7_ContactForm` which is passed to the hook `wpcf7_before_send_mail`

Use the method `prop` to access `mail` from there.

At this point, you can hook the mail and update the output however you want.  Use  `$contact_form->set_properties(array('mail' => $mail));` to update the mail body to whatever you want.  There is no need to return the function, as you're updating the object directly.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'dd_handle_form_submission' );
function dd_handle_form_submission( $contact_form ) {
    $mail = $contact_form->prop('mail')['body'];

    // Output the content to the error log of your website.
    ob_start();
    echo $mail;
    error_log(ob_get_clean());

    // Use this to push new content to the mail before sending
    $mail = $new_mail_content // whatever you set it to
    $contact_form->set_properties(array('mail' => $mail));

}
```

**UPDATED Answer:**

To get the content of the email after variable replacement, you have to use the filter `wpcf7_mail_components`

`$components` is an array of the mail components

`['subject', 'sender', 'body', 'recipient', 'additional_headers', 'attachments']`

Since this function has no output to the screen, you would have to send it to the error log to debug it.

```php
add_filter('wpcf7_mail_components', 'filter_mail_components', 10, 3);
function filter_mail_components($components, $current_form, $mail_class){
    ob_start();
    print_r($components['body']);
    error_log(ob_get_clean());
    return $components;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried exactly that but it's not my question. Please check edit for clarification.

Comment: Works great! You rock! That's exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons contact form 7 doesn't allow html but using below hook you can get the form data & send email in html format.

```
// define the wpcf7_before_send_mail callback 
function action_wpcf7_before_send_mail( $contact_form ) {
 
    // Use wp_mail() to send an email. To send html in body first add_filter with content type text/html within this function

add_filter('wp_mail_content_type', function( $content_type ) {
            return 'text/html';
});
//Send email..... Even you can put php variable values within html
wp_mail( 'me@example.net', 'your_subject', '<div>The message</div>' );

}; 
         
// add the action 
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'action_wpcf7_before_send_mail', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: CF7 does allow sending email as HTML. Also, my question is how to get the final output... not how to create a new template.